# Spring boot Neo4j - Dynamic Projection

Tags: spring, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I would like to implement a dynamic projection for Neo4j repository of my spring application.

The dynamic projection that I want to implement is like user input the field that they want in the request parameter when making HTTP POST request and I take that input to limit the field that I want.

In their document, it said that the projections in supported but only simple projection not the dynamic projection and in the other material does not seems to mention this technique at all.

So does spring boot Neo4j support dynamic projection or is there another tricky way to do that?

Now I am using Spring-Neo4j version 5.0.10.RELEASE

Comment: can you please explain some more or any example.

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? If you just need data as a map, there is an annotation for storing all unspecified properties in a map field. If you need dynamic type return, what are you trying to do that you don't know what you are returning?